# Do I need to use virtual environment while using docker?

Tags: django, docker, virtualenv

I didn't know what is the benefit of Docker over virtual environment. Is it necessary to use virtual environment and docker at the same time.

Before today, Basically I used virtual environment to crate Django project. But today My friend recommended me to use docker. I'm confused what should i use ?

I used this command to create virtual environment
`python3 -m venv virtual_environment_name`
Is this is best way to create virtual environment or should i use another way to create virtual environment

Answer (score 3):

I would rather use pipenv to replace virtualenv at local development environment, and docker without virtual environment at production. Here is my Dockerfile(run django with gunicorn):

```
FROM python:3.6

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# switch system download source
RUN python -c "s='mirrors.163.com';import re;from pathlib import Path;p=Path('/etc/apt/sources.list');p.write_text(re.sub(r'(deb|security)\.debian\.org', s, p.read_text()))"
RUN apt-get update

# aliyun source for pip
RUN python -c "s='mirrors.aliyun.com';from pathlib import Path;p=Path.home()/'.pip';p.mkdir();(p/'pip.conf').write_text(f'[global]\nindex-url=https://{s}/pypi/simple\n[install]\ntrusted-host={s}\n')"

# Optional: install and conf vim, install ipython
RUN apt-get install -y vim
RUN wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/waketzheng/carstino/master/.vimrc
RUN pip install ipython

# copy source code to docker image
WORKDIR /carrot
ADD . .

# required packages for carrot
RUN apt-get install -y ruby-sass

# install gunicorn and Pipfile
RUN pip install pipenv gunicorn
RUN pipenv install --system
RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput

# database name and rpc server ip
ENV POSTGRES_HOST=db
ENV RPC_SERVER_IP=172.21.0.2

EXPOSE 9000

# the PASSWORD env should be replace to a real one
CMD ["gunicorn", "--bind", ":9000", "--env", "PASSWORD=123456", "--error-logfile", "gunicorn.error", "--log-file", "gunicorn.log", "carrot.wsgi:application"]
```